# Eigenvalue of endomorphism, eigenvalue of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V$ be some finite-dimensional $K$-vector space and $f\colon V\to V$ some endomorphism.

Show:

If $\lambda\in K$ is some eigenvalue of $f$ and $p(X)\in K[X]$, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(f)$.

---

Did not really find a proof.
Let $\lambda$ be some eigenvalue of $f$, that is, there exists some $v\in V, v\neq 0$ such that $f(v)=\lambda v$. My idea was to show that
$$
p(f)(v)=p(f(v))=p(\lambda v)=p(\lambda)(v)
$$

but I was not able to do so.

Comment: "$p(f(v))$" means nothing. $p$ is a polynomial and $f(v)$ is a vector.

Comment: But isn't $p(f)$ an endomorphism from V to V?

Comment: Yes, so $(p(f))(v)$ means something,  but not $p(f(v)).$

Comment: This is not analysis, but it *is* linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you may note that if $p$ is a monomial $p(x)=cx^n$ the statement is obvious as
$$
p(f)v=cf^nv=c\lambda f^{n-1}v=c\lambda^2 f^{n-2}v=\ldots=c\lambda^n v=p(\lambda)v
$$
for $v$ an eigenvector of $f$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

For an arbitrary $p=\sum c_nx^n$ you can simply apply the above
$$
p(f)v=\sum c_nf^nv=\sum c_n\lambda^nv=p(\lambda)v.
$$

Comment: $(p(f))(v)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_kf^k\right)(v)=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_k f^k(v)=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_k\lambda^kv=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_k\lambda^k\right)(v)=p(\lambda)(v)$ --- Correct?

Comment: Yes totally correct.